# why this code gives error output in visualization

Tags: exploratory-data-analysis

*col = 'sex'
colors = px.colors.qualitative.Plotly
fig = px.bar(medical_df[col].value_counts().reset_index(), x=medical_df.index, y=col, title=f"{col.capitalize()} Distribution", color='index', color_discrete_sequence=colors)